# Android Auto: Google Play Music

Tags: google-play-music, android-auto

So this seems like an obvious "yes, of course it has to" but I can't find anything *official* that will commit to it.

Are all Android Auto consoles guaranteed to support Google Play Music, since it's an Android Auto app?

Perhaps more broadly: When would an Android Auto app *not* be supported by a given Android Auto console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Auto is just a display interface app on your head unit. It doesn't control what types of Android apps are allowed, and it doesn't actually run the app itself. That's all done by the smartphone connecting to the head unit.

If you can install the app on your smartphone and it supports Android Auto, it'll be there. Thus the only time Google Play Music won't be supported is if your smartphone doesn't support it.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you answering this! I had assumed it would go unanswered. I went ahead and took the plunge and downloaded it, and saw that this was the case.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be: "_Thus the only time Google Play Music won't be supported is if this app doesn't support Android Auto_"? Your smartphone can surely support given app, but as long as that app's developer won't include Android Auto-enabled functionality inside this application, it won't work with the car.

Comment: I mentioned Google Play Music specifically in response to the original question, which was just about the Google Play Music app.